# Drupal Slow loading times

Tags: users, nodes

I'm currently having a Drupal 6 (because some modules are not available in Drupal 7) site running. But the loading time is very slow(www.hard-dance.org)

Here's what I've tried so far to eliminate possible reasons:

1. I have looked in my admin panel for problems, and did a cron job manually
2. I have checked to see if Clean-URLs was causing the site to slow down, it was not.
3. I've disabled some modules, but no change.

I also noticed that my website is going slow, **once logged in.**

Does anyone have an idea of what the cause of it could be?

Comment: What sort of hosting are you running on?

Comment: http://translate.google.be/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=nl&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fversio.be%2Fwebhosting.php 

I'm using the "Starter package"

Maybe this can help too:
MySQL database for event module 5.1.68
MySQL-database 5.1.68
PHP 5.2.17
PHP-memorylimit 128M

Comment: Logged in users skip most of the caches. Solution is to build functionalities on views and cache views by query and by block. And disable modules that cannot cache their own data properly.

Comment: I agree with @Molot, it sounds like there's not enough caching for logged-in users. There's a whole bunch of modules that will help with that. This page is a good starting point. https://groups.drupal.org/node/21897

Comment: With no *real* information, this problem can't really be diagnosed.  I also think because of this it is far too broad.  there are LOTS of questions and answers if you check the [tag:performance] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Check size of files folder, heavy images may increase site loading time.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many different factors which can contribute to a slow site to include in one answer.

What I did notice when viewing your site is that you're not using any cache'ing or CSS/JS aggregation. These should definately be configured as the very minimum starting point for performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the apache log. located at /var/logs/apache2/error.log
2. Check the all the processes using ps -e or ps -A to show all the processes

Comment: Check them for what?

Comment: errors and processes that seem odd